# The difference between the order of displaying elements on the page and their downloading to the list

Tags: javascript, java, testing

I have a problem. The website, when indicating the sorting of products by price from the lowest to the highest, displays the sorted products correctly, but it downloads them to the created list in the ID order. The assertion fails. Please help. Only the first and last price of the product in the list are in order. That's why I only check them in the code. The downloaded list on the console displays like this
€34.80
€34.80
€34.80
€10.80
€10.80
€10.80
€42.00Below
I put the test code.

@Test
public void sortowanieProduktuArt() {

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Art')]")).click();
   
    String art = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li /span[contains(.,\"Art\")]")).getText().toLowerCase();
    
    Assertions.assertTrue(art.contains("art"));
   
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-unstyle.select-title")).click();
   
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"dropdown-menu\"]/a[contains(.,\"Price, low to high\")]"))).click();
   
    List<WebElement> cenyProduktow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='price']"));
   
    List<Double> ceny = new ArrayList<>();
   
    for (WebElement cenaProduktu : cenyProduktow) {
       
        String cena = cenaProduktu.getText().replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
       
        double konwersjaCeny = Double.parseDouble(cena); //Dodanie zmiennej konwesja ceny do listy Double
        ceny.add(konwersjaCeny);
    }

    double pierwszaCena = ceny.get(0);
   
    double ostatniaCena = ceny.get(ceny.size() - 1);
 
    System.out.println("Pierwsza cena: " + pierwszaCena);
    System.out.println("Ostatnia cena: " + ostatniaCena);
  
    boolean isSorted = pierwszaCena < ostatniaCena;
   
    String komunikat = "Ceny sa od najmniejszej do najwiekszej : " + isSorted;
   
    System.out.println(komunikat);
  
    Assertions.assertTrue(isSorted, komunikat);
}
```

Do you know any way to check all items in the list at the same time passing assertions?